# Pandas: from_csv gives error

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I use Pandas 0.12.0 and definded a read csv function as follows:

```
df=pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(inputpfad,index_col=2, parse_dates=[0,5], 
                             infer_datetime_format=True)
```

However, I got as error message:

```
TypeError: from_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'infer_datetime_format'
```

I set it to true to speed up the parsing. Might it not be supported
in my Pandas-version?

Comment: This was added [2 weeks ago](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6021), so it's not in `0.12`. It is in the current version `0.13.1`.